# How to use asp identity with mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to figure out how to do a login in my asp net project. I have a mysql database and I've read Identity is good for this. The tutorials I have seen online seem to create a new project with the option individual user accounts and it creates the identity files. I'm using visual studio for mac and it doesn't give me the option. I have added already the userroles,users,userclaims,roles,userclaims to my mysql database but I don't know how to proceed next.  I have already installed the entity packages and entity.mysql packages too. I downloaded the app_start folder with the identity files, don't know if I needed to do that.

I have read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/implementing-a-custom-mysql-aspnet-identity-storage-provider